# ORM for Tornado

Tags: python, forms, orm, sqlalchemy, tornado

I use mongodb in the most of my tornado work But now I'm working on a project and sql-db with this project will be better I tried before django orm + tornado, SQLAlchemy + tornado

What is the best simplest ORM for tornado Async ?

Is there any restriction for using SQlAlchemy With tornado ?

What are the available "sessions" and "forms" available for todnado ( I'm using wtforms )

Thank You :)

Comment: I used SQLAlchemy and its good. SQLAlchemy is fully orm dedicated tool. You will get most of the functions you can do with sql by SQLA.

Comment: did you work with different SQLA decelerative ?

Comment: I work on SQLA Declarative but different in which context ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out my solution for SQLAlchemy, http://lepture.com/work/mysql-sqlalchemy/

I have fixed mysql has gone away, and have a solution for master and slave database, and make it easier to use.

For form part, I have create a project at github:[lepture/tforms](https://github.com/lepture/tforms) to make it i18n support, and fix many unicode bug of wtforms, it may not good enough, take your risk.

Comment: Thank you :) ... This is what I was looking fot besides I have many problems wihth wtofotms I'll try tforms

Comment: @AbdAllah, you need to accept this answer since it answered your question. Click the check mark to the left of this user's answer.

Comment: @lepture We use your forms and how I can see you only write wrapper around tornado request for wtforms processing, as I know what's because wtforms wait MultiDict or Dict-like object. But many thx. ))

Comment: @Denis You need to take care of it, since it is not well maintained.